# Multiset With Structures

Tags: c++, structure, multiset

I want to declare a multiset of a structure.
The current form of my declaration of multiset is

```
struct obj
{
   //code
};

struct compare
{
    inline bool operator()(const obj &a, const obj &b)
    {
    //code
    }
};
multiset<obj,compare> mst;
```

Is there any other form of declaration which may use only one structre by overloading operator for *obj*.

Comment: If you don't need different comparators you could add `bool operator<<(const obj&) const;` in your `struct obj`. I don't think it'll be faster though, but less to think about.

Comment: The style of comparator is likely to have much less impact than the fact that you're using a node-based rb-tree set in the first place. If you're worried about performance (after you actually wrote some working code and benchmarked it), look for a container with better than logarithmic time and/or cache-friendly layout.

Comment: Implement a global function operator<(const obj& lhs, const obj& rhs). multiset uses std::less<Key> by default which in turn uses the operator< of the class/struct. If you care for performance, the usual answer is std::vector.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad eh? How does `std::multiset` relate to `std::vector` in any way?

Comment: If you have less than some amount of objects (like 1k) and care for performance, vector is usually the right answer. Of course the semantics are different :)

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad a right answer for **what**? If you need an ordered container of your objects, which supports log(N) insertions/deletions, which `std::multiset` is, vector is **not** the answer.

Comment: The right answer for performance. The std implementations for map, set, ... are slower for a few objects. Sure, they are log(N) but with a higher constant. vector + linear/binary search instead of set is going to be faster.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad I do not think we are talking about the same thing. How performant do you think insertions into such a vector would be? When you insert in a middle? I suggest you actually write the code, test the performance (use a good struct with non-trivial constructors and destructors) and than report back with actual numbers.

Comment: That's the point :D As long as you have a sane amount of stuff (the number depends on the actual machine) the vector is always going to be faster. Google it. That's why there are various flat_map implementations.

Comment: You are of course right for non trivial or many objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can overload operator `<` for your struct, either as a member function or as a free-standing one. This will make code more concise (in my purely subjective opinion), but in practice would not lead to any difference in performance.

As a matter of fact, optimizing compiler is more than likely to generate exactly the same code (provided the actual comparison code is the same).